# Stream relay with Red5 Media Server

Tags: java, streaming, video-streaming, red5

I write an (Java-) application that streams a video from one peer to another. I use a library that is able to produce and consume an RTP stream (Xuggler that is). I thought about using Red5 Media Server to relay the stream. What I need next is to send  and  my video stream.

The documentation I read so far always deals with recording streams or streaming prerecorded videos (and of course the web cam). Also there is quiet some amount of Actionscript code that does not help me at the time. (I belief...)

So my question is: *Can Red5 help me?* (I.e. should I continue reading or is there another - more direct - solution?) Could you please give me some pointer where I would find suitable documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red5 is primarily for streaming to Flash clients over RTMP,RTMPT,RTMPS etc. It is not limited to these protocols, but they are the ones available "out of the box". If you want to run xuggler inside red5 to consume RTP and then publish to RTMP then you are in luck as this is very ez to do. If you want to republish as RTP, you have some additional work cut out for you.